# Possible to have a job depend on another repo?

Tags: travis-ci

We have a project where there are integration tests for the web-services implemented in the mobile projects.  Would it be possible, for instance, to build and run a test target in the iOS repo every time the back-end is deployed? If so how would one go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box.

You could however use the *trigger a build* feature during a build on the backend repository, so a build on the frontend repository is started.

See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds/ for the required building blocks.

Downside is that you will not see a build error in the right place.

Alternative is to clone the frontend repository in a separate job on the backend repository, and run the tests there. This means that breaking changes in the backend will be visible in the GitHub UI.